# How to make F# Giraffe default route points to /health?

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

I have the following `Program.fs`:

```ml
let webApp = choose [ setStatusCode 404 >=> text "Not Found" ]

let errorHandler (ex : Exception) (logger : ILogger) =
    logger.LogError(ex, "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.")
    clearResponse >=> setStatusCode 500 >=> text ex.Message

let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    app.UseHealthChecks(PathString("/health")) |> ignore
    let env = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>()
    (match env.IsDevelopment() with
    | true  -> app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
    | false -> app.UseGiraffeErrorHandler errorHandler)
        .UseHttpsRedirection()
        .UseStaticFiles()
        .UseGiraffe(webApp)

let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddHealthChecks() |> ignore
    services.AddCors()    |> ignore
    services.AddGiraffe() |> ignore

let configureLogging (builder : ILoggingBuilder) =
    builder.AddFilter(fun l -> l.Equals LogLevel.Error)
           .AddConsole()
           .AddDebug() |> ignore

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let contentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    let webRoot     = Path.Combine(contentRoot, "WebRoot")
    WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseWebRoot(webRoot)
        .Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)
        .ConfigureServices(configureServices)
        .ConfigureLogging(configureLogging)
        .Build()
        .Run()
    0
```

I would like that the default endpoint target the health check (ie. `/health`), how is that possible using F# Giraffe?

Comment: not sure what do you mean by "default route". but I guess you might benefit from this https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#redirection

Comment: @Bohdan Stupak thanks it helped actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the article given in comment: https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#redirection

and ended up on the following `choose`:

```ml
let webApp = choose [
                GET >=>
                    choose [
                        route "/" >=> redirectTo false "/health"
                    ]
                setStatusCode 404 >=> text "Not Found" ]
```